# How to detect a "pinch to zoom" gestre with "ScaleGestureDetecor "?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ontouchlistener, pinchzoom

I have an ImageButton and I'd like to listen to gestures. How could i detect a "pinch to zoom" gestre and to know if it meant to be a zoom in or a zoom out?

Comment: you need `ScaleGestureDetecor`

Comment: @pskink Thanks, updated. Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: implement the `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener`

Comment: try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pinch